# Cite R packages to EndNote in FEMS style using Package "citeRpackages"

Tags: r, citations

I am trying to cite R, R Studio, and couple R packages using FEMS citation style and wanted to import the citation package to my EndNote and cite them in the word file I am writing using EndNote.

I found this very nice package citeRpackages: https://github.com/jrgant/citeRpackages

However,
The `install.packages("citeRpackages")` is not working for R version 3.4.2

The `devtools::install_github("jrgant/citeRpackages")` is not working for the error message:

> Downloading GitHub repo jrgant/citeRpackages@master
>   from URL https://api.github.com/repos/jrgant/citeRpackages/zipball/master
>   Installation failed: Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: You could download it from github and add it to your function collection, it is just one small function.

Comment: Thanks jaySf. There is one extra thing you need to do if you want to use this function and upload the .bib text into EndNote. EndNote8 currently does not have the filter for .bib format references. You can download Citavi and import.bib to Citavi and export to RIS file and then upload to EndNote. It worked out for me.